# How I get the Model Class to when I am passing in a generic in my method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, generic-method, tracker-enabled-dbcontext

I m using [tracker-enabled-dbcontext](https://github.com/bilal-fazlani/tracker-enabled-dbcontext/) and using [documentation](https://tracker-enabled-dbcontext.bilal-fazlani.com/configuration/) to capture DB audit logs, configure tracking we need to be used

```
EntityTracker
.TrackAllProperties<NormalModel>()
.Except(x => x.Description)
.And(x => x.Id);
```

I have multiple Model classes so I decide to control the configuration dynamically. so
I need to retrieve the Model class using namespace and pass it to the TrackAllProperties method.

I tried to like this,

```
Type test = Type.GetType("Mark.Domain.assets.AssetsSettings");
TrackerEnabledDbContext.Common.Configuration.EntityTracker.TrackAllProperties<test>();
```

but it does not accept "test" Type

This is the TrackAllProperties method. **I'm not allowed to modify the following method**

```
public static TrackAllResponse<T> TrackAllProperties<T>()
    {
        OverrideTracking<T>().Enable();

        var allPublicInstanceProperties = typeof (T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        //add high priority tracking to all properties
        foreach (var property in allPublicInstanceProperties)
        {
            Func<PropertyConfiguerationKey, TrackingConfigurationValue, TrackingConfigurationValue> factory =
                (key,value) => new TrackingConfigurationValue(true, TrackingConfigurationPriority.High);

            TrackingDataStore.PropertyConfigStore.AddOrUpdate(
                new PropertyConfiguerationKey(property.Name, typeof (T).FullName),
                new TrackingConfigurationValue(true, TrackingConfigurationPriority.High),
                factory
                );
        }

        return new TrackAllResponse<T>();
    }
```

How I can achieve this task

Answer (score 0):

To pass the generic type, try this code instead:

```
TrackerEnabledDbContext.Common.Configuration.EntityTracker.TrackAllProperties<Mark.Domain.assets.AssetsSettings>();
```

The generic type argument `T` should be the actual model class rather than a type object of the model class. It's the same construct as declaring a `List<string>` - you don't have to get a type object for string.

Update:

In response to your comment, here is some code that you could try to get this working with variables, but I do not recommend this approach.  You can read more about the Invoke call [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=net-6.0#system-reflection-methodbase-invoke(system-object-system-object())). It may need to be modified to fit your application. Again, I do not recommend this approach.

```
var method = typeof(TrackerEnabledDbContext.Common.Configuration.EntityTracker).GetMethod("TrackAllProperties");
var trackMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(test); // your type variable
trackMethod.Invoke(TrackerEnabledDbContext.Common.Configuration.EntityTracker, null);
```

Comment: But @John Glenn I need to dynamically load those classes. because I have 50+ classes to load like that, with if-else conditions. Can I have a solution for this?

Comment: @user3732708 See the update to this answer. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for your response John, Actually, it gave an error ``` 'EntityTracker' is a type, which is not valid in the given context```  for the last line of the above code